# How to create a short circuit evaluation in bison using mid-rules action?

Tags: c++, bison, ternary-operator

I was assigned to write a calculator that, among some other things, also supports variables definition and assignments, boolean expressions and decrement/increment operations.
My calculator should also support the conditional (ternary) operation `? :`, the same kind some programming languages support, which used as follows:

```
condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false ;
```

Or as it defined in my grammar rules:

```
bool_expression ? int_expression : int_expression ;
```

The problem is, it has to be a [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), meaning that if *bool_expression* evaluates to true, only the first *int_expression* should be evaluated, and otherwise, if *bool_expression* evaluates to false, then only the second *int_expression* should be evaluated.

I was told to use bison's [Action in mid-rule](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/bison/bison_6.html#SEC48) functionality, but I fail to see how could that be of help.

I also looked around online and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660291/initiating-short-circuit-rule-in-bison-for-and-operations) to be the closest thing to what I'm trying to accomplish, but unfortunately, the answer there is not quite what I'm looking for. The answer there indeed describes what should be done, but does not state specifically how to do it (global flag is out of the question, you'll understand why when you'll see the code).

Here's a very small part from what I have so far:

```
%{
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <map>

    using namespace std;

    map<string, int> symbolTable;

    int yylex();
    void yyerror(const char*);

%}

%union{
    int     int_val;
    char*   string_val;
    bool b;
}


%token <int_val> T_NUMBER
%token <string_val> T_VAR
%type  <int_val> expr
%type  <b>bool_expression
%nonassoc ':'
%nonassoc T_EQUALS
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%left UMINUS
%left '$' '~'



%%

commands:   
        /* eps rule */      {cout<<"create commands"<<endl;}
        | commands command  {cout<<"add command"<<endl;};


command:    expr '\n'       {cout<<"Expression value: "<<$1<<endl;}
    |   T_VAR '=' expr '\n' {cout<<"Assignment: "<<$1<<"="<<$3<<endl; symbolTable[$1] = $3;}
    |   bool_expression '\n'    {$1 ? cout<<"true"<<endl : cout<<"false"<<endl;}
    ;

expr:
        T_NUMBER        {$$ = $1;}
    |   T_VAR           {$$ = symbolTable[$1];}
    |   expr '+' expr       {$$ = $1 + $3;}
    |   expr '-' expr       {$$ = $1 - $3;}
    |   expr '*' expr       {$$ = $1 * $3;}
    |   expr '/' expr       {if ($3 == 0) {yyerror ("Division by zero!"); return 1;} $$ = $1 / $3;}
    |   '$' T_VAR       {$$ = ++symbolTable[$2]; }
    |   '~' T_VAR       {$$ = --symbolTable[$2]; }
    |   '-' expr %prec UMINUS   {$$=-$2;}
    |   bool_expression '?'     {/* this is a mid-rule; what should go here... */}
        expr ':' expr       {/* in order to evaluates only one of these two, depending on bool_expression */}
    ;

bool_expression:  expr T_EQUALS expr        {$$=($1==$3);}

%%  

void yyerror(const char* errorInfo){
    cout<<errorInfo<<endl;
}

int main(){
    yyparse();
}
```

the '$' operator you see there has the same meaning as the operator ++ in C, and the '~' operator has the same meaning as --.

Back to my problem: the above is only the relevant code, I have a lot more rules I've omitted for the sake of readability. This also means that using some global flag is not my best choice here, since it will require its inspection in **every rule in my file**.
Now, consider the input:

a=5
1==1 ? $a : $a

And the naive approach of defining the above rule as:

```
|   bool_expression '?' expr ':' expr {$1 ? $$=$3 : $$=$5 ;}
```

this code results in 'a' having the value 7 instead of 6.
So how can 'action in mid-rule' be used here to prevent the first expr to ever be shifted/reduced if *bool_expression* is false, and prevent the second expr to be shifted/reduced if *bool_expression* is true?

Comment: "This also means that using some global flag is not my best choice here, since it will require its inspection in every rule in my file." That doesn't mean it isn't your best choice. If all your other choices are equally or even more sucky (and they very likely are - assuming creating a proper AST isn't allowed by the assignment), this is still your best choice.

Comment: With what you have here, `$` and `~` have no effect, ever.  They are not equivalent to `++` or `--`.  The expression `$$ = $2++` just increments a temporary value that is about the be thrown away, not the value of the symbol that was read for the expression that set `$2` originally

Comment: @ChrisDodd You're right, that should have been T_VAR there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a global flag `eval` which is set (true) while parsing code that should be evaluated.  While it is false, the parser should just skip over things and not actually evaluate anything.  So your rule for assignment becomes:

```
command: T_VAR '=' expr '\n' {
    if (eval) {
        cout << "Assignment: " << $1 << "=" << $3 << endl;
        symbolTable[$1] = $3; } }
```

Similarly for all other rules that might have side effects (for those that have no side effects, you can run unconditionally and generate a value that will be ignored, or you can similarly guard it.)

Then, your conditional rule becomes:

```
expr: expr { if ($$ = eval) eval = $1; } '?'
      expr { if ($2) eval = !eval; } ':'
      expr { if (eval = $2) $$ = $1 ? $4 : $7; }
```

This saves the `eval` flag in the result of the first inline action, restores it in the final action and, if it was set, sets it for the expression that should be evaluated and not for the other.

One big problem with this is that error recovery becomes much harder, since you need to figure out when/where to restore the `eval` flag.

**edit**

With what you have abouve, `$` and `~` don't actually do anything.  If you want them to be equivalent to `++` and `--`, you need:

```
expr: `$` T_VAR { $$ = eval ? symbolTable[$2]++ : 0; }
    | `~` T_VAR { $$ = eval ? symbolTable[$2]-- : 0; }
```